Cardinality of all functions mapping from power sets
If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, let $F(X, Y)$ be the set of functions mapping from $X$ to $Y$. My question is, if $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets, is the cardinality of $F(A,B)<F(P(A),P(B))$, where $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$ and $P(B)$ is the power set of $B$?
I misread a textbook problem and interpreted this to be the question (the question asked turned out to be different) and weeks later I still haven't proved it.
I tried to use Cantor's proof that $\#P(A)>\#A$ to do some things, but none of them work because the functions in $F(A,B)$ have shared input and outputs and aren't unique like how it works in Cantor's proof.

At least the negation of this statement is consistent with ZFC. Assuming the GCH, then $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\omega + 1}$. Indeed, by König’s theorem, as $\text{cf}(\aleph_\omega) = \aleph_0$, we have $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_\omega$. But,
$$\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0} \leq (2^{\aleph_\omega})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_\omega \times \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_\omega} = \aleph_{\omega + 1}$$
So, $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\omega + 1}$. On the other hand, we also have,
$$(2^{\aleph_\omega})^{(2^{\aleph_0})} = (2^{\aleph_\omega})^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_\omega \times \aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_\omega} = \aleph_{\omega + 1}$$
